# vsftp ignoring local_root and goes to home dir instead

Tags: ftp, root, vsftpd

I have setup vsftp multiple times with these settings without ever having a problem. But I recently got a new server which for some reason seems to ignore local_root. I have a user that if logged into FTP, should automatically be redirected to the website dir in /var/www. However, with the current config it goes to the user's home dir /home/myuser. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

**/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
seccomp_sandbox=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
file_open_mode=0777
local_umask=022
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/users
rsa_cert_file=/var/www/example.com/ssl/chain.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/var/www/example.com/ssl/privkey.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

**/etc/vsftpd/users/myuser**

```
local_root=/var/www/example.com/
dirlist_enable=YES
download_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
```

When logged in, it goes to /home/myuser instead of /var/www/example.com/